# VBA Excel "what" is not looking any longer in .find method

Tags: excel, vba

I found a problem when I'm running one macro that I wrote. I am not able to find the root.

I am looking for all values in a column containing the word RCS with my sub "`FindMultipleOccurrences`". The sub is working well in case I don't call another sub called "`RCS`" where I am also doing a find for some empty values.

But if RCS sub is call the sub "`FindMultipleOccurrences`" does not look any more for RCS entries but for empty values.

How can I avoid that problem?

My macros (please notice both macros unfinished yet):

```
Sub FindMultipleOccurrences()

    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngLast As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    Worksheets("RCS").Range("B5:J1000").Delete

    Set rngSearch = Worksheets("Ongoing").Range("B:B")
    Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)

    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="RCS", After:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'buscando  RCS

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
        Do
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
            MsgBox rngFound.Address
          '  Call RCS(rngFound) 
        Loop Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Makro 2:

```
Sub RCS(rngo As Range)

    Set Row1 = Range(rngo.Address).Offset(7, -1).Resize(, 13).Find("", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Row1 Is Nothing Then
            Set row2 = Range(rngo.Address).Offset(8, -1).Resize(, 13).Find("", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If row2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rower = Range(rngo.Address).Offset(9, -1).Resize(, 13).Find("", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            Else
                Set rower = row2
            End If
    Else
        Set rower = Row1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a second `.Find` command you are essentially cancelling the first and subsequent `.FindNext` commands will not carry on from the original `.Find`.

Use alternate methods to achieve your offset blank cell location.

```
If CBool(Application.CountBlank(Range(rngo.Address).Offset(7, -1).Resize(, 13))) Then
    Set Rower = Range(rngo.Address).Offset(7, -1).Resize(, 13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1)
```

It is unclear to me what the successive operations are intended to achieve. If you are looking in a column for blanks and cannot find anything then moving the range down one cell and searching again shouldn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeeped. I will try what you say